# Multiple ANOVAs, shall I correct the homogeneity of variance test?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, heteroscedasticity

I want to run nine different ANOVAs on different variables that may change among groups. The ANOVAs are preceded by the Levene test of variance homogeneity. Of course, I want to correct for multiple comparisons in the final alpha threshold for the ANOVAs.

But as random p values can be under 0.05 in all tests, the same should happen to the Levene test, am I right?

So my question is, shall I correct the Levene test results also for multiple comparisons?

What argument can it be not to correct the homogeneity test the same was the results from those data are corrected for multiple comparisons?